# Is the .bashrc executed in linux when #/bin/bash is included in a script?

Tags: bash

If I write `#/bin/bash` at the top of a script and call this script from a web based application, will this load the `.bashrc` file on the machine where shell script is located?

Answer (score 4):

The bash manual [describes which startup files are read under which conditions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files).  From it you would glean that `bash` reads `.bashrc` automatically only when invoked as an interactive, non-login shell, with neither the `--norc` option nor an `--rcfile` option naming a different file.

Note, however:

- In addition to its default criteria for considering itself "interactive", `bash` considers itself interactive if invoked with the `-i` option.  You can use this to cause `~/.bashrc` to be read at startup when `bash` is invoked to run a script.
- A non-interactive shell can be made to read a particular startup file (which can, in turn, read others) by specifying its name as the value of variable `BASH_ENV` in the shell's initial environment.
- If it is read automatically, it is the *user's* `~/.bashrc` that is read -- this is a characteristic of the user running the script, not of the machine overall.

Answer (score 1):

No. `.bashrc` are relevant to *interactive* shells only.

Comment: Won't Bash still load the `.bashrc` but do nothing once it reaches `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`? So if you put commands above that line then they would be executed.

Comment: @JonnyHenly, no, it won't. Whoever put `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` in your `.bashrc` was cargo-culting it, rather than actually doing something that makes sense in light of documented or actual behavior. Sadly, there's a lot of cargo-culting in bash, even in folks who should know better (like those who are working for Linux distributors).

Comment: @JonnyHenly, ...of course, it could also be that they're doing some kind of hackery like setting a `BASH_ENV` variable pointing to `$HOME/.bashrc`, but that's... well... hackery, making the shell behave contrary to its documentation (and thus reasonable peoples' expectations).